# Mutex Console Release

Tags: c#

This is a console application Wqhen i run the below program it shows a single console
and  i have executed 3 other console from bin directory now my question is
When 1 console is  has been has completed its task . Control  is not going to other console
 it is showing the same display Running(Console 1). How does Running show on other consoles.

```
class Program
{
    static Mutex m = new Mutex(true, "demo");

    public static void Main()
    {
        if (!m.WaitOne(1000))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("another");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                run();
            }
            finally
            {
                m.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("running");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
          m.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear how these programs get started.  But if you do it from the command line then they'll all share the same console.  Then again, it will be hard to start more than one at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

your program would be getting stuck due to readline where it holds for user input, try to use mutex like eg below

```
using (var mutex = new Mutex(false, "demo"))
 {
        mutex.WaitOne(); 
        run(); 
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
}
```